# Can I set the property of a new object to a value of the object its created in implicitly

Tags: php

Im late to the party and just getting started learning OOP PHP.
Im hoping that I can do something along the following lines.

```
class Thingy {
  public $uuid;

  function __construct() {
    $this->uuid = 'abc123';
  }
  function AddHandle() {
    $handle = new Handle();
    return $handle;
  } 
  ...
}

class Handle {
  public $parent;

  function __contruct () {
    $this->parent = **UUID OF THE OBJECT THAT CREATED A NEW INSTANCE**;
  }
  ...
}
```

This way I wouldnt need to pass the UUID of the calling object to the object its creating.
Is this a silly idea?
Should I always pass the UUID of the calling object?

```
function AddHandle() {
    $handle = new Handle($this->uuid);
    return $handle;
}
```

and then pass $this->uuid through the constructor for Handle?

Like I said im just getting started.
If I answered my own question, great, let me know.
If not could someone help me, or point me in the right direction? 
It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you should always pass the UUID to Handle, and add params to Handle constructor  function __contruct ($uuid) { $this->parent = $uuid;}

Comment: thank you for your input.  Id mark it as the answer if I could